# fill object from a returned dataset in C#

Tags: c#, object, dataset

I have a webservice which calls an Oracle stored procedure and gets back a dataset without hassle.
I have also created a class (below) which I would like to fill from the dataset and return this rather than the dataset but Im not sure how, could anyone give me a starter or point me in the direction of a decent example?

thanks

```
namespace Models
{
[DataContract]
public class PaymentAccDetails
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string PaymentRef
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public DateTime StartDate
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public DateTime EndDate
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    public string AccountType
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    [DataMember(Order = 5)]
    public string PaymentMethod
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    [DataMember(Order = 6)]
    public DateTime LastPaidDate
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    [DataMember(Order = 7)]
    public string Balance
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: What have you tried? What is the problem? Why don't you simply create an instance of the object for each row and assign each value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are currently using a DataAdapter to fill the DataSet but would rather like a List of strongly typed objects, it might be faster and more direct to use a DataReader instead.

```
using (DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
  while (reader.Read()) {
    PaymentAccDetails pad = new PaymentAccDetails();
    pad.PaymentRef = reader.GetString(0);
    [fill other properties]
    [add to list]
  }
}
```

Comment: looks interesting as I am using a DataAdapter, once Ive set all the properties, can you tell me how to add each row to the list? thanks

Answer (score 3):

Create a constructor for the class which takes a `DataRow` and build up the object from that:

```
public PaymentAccDetails (DataRow row)
{
     this.PaymentMethod = row["PaymentMethod"].ToString();
     this.AccountType = row["AccountType"].ToString();
     //etc...
}
```

Call it like:

```
foreach(DataRow row in dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    PaymentAccDetails acctDetails = new PaymentAccDetails(row);
    //add to a collection
}
```

Comment: +1 A very workable solution, especially if LINQ isn't an option. And honestly, it's becoming a theme. People are working on older applications that can't be upgraded for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2):

```
var paymentDetails = dataSet.Tables[i].AsEnumerable()
                         .Select(r => new PaymentAccDetails
                         {
                             PaymentRef = r[n],
                             StartDate = r[o],
                             ...
                         }
                         .ToList();
```

where `i` is the index of the table, `n` is the index of the `PaymentRef` field, and `o` is the index of the `StartDate` field, and so on.

Comment: we can omit the `Rows`?

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions, should get it sorted now.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, this is how I would like to do it - this way you know exactly what you are receiving back from the Web Service:

```
public List<PaymentAccDetails> GetPaymentAccDetails()
{
   var paymentAccDetailsList = new List<PaymentAccDetails>();
   using (var conn = new SqlConnection(/*ConnectionString*/))
   { 
        conn.Open();
        using (var cmd  = new SqlCommand("YourStoredProcedure", conn))
        {
             cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
             using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
             {
                 while (reader.Read())
                 {
                     var paymentAccDetails = new PaymentAccDetails();
                     paymentAccDetails.PaymentMethod = Convert.ToString(row["PaymentMethod"]);
                     paymentAccDetails.AccountType = Convert.ToString(row["AccountType"]);
                     ... etc.
                     paymentAccDetailsList.Add(paymentAccDetails);
                 }
             }
        }
    }
    return paymentAccDetailsList;
}
```